Quelle serait la forme verbale plus adaptée à la phrase au vu du contexte présenté (voir le corps de la question)?
1- Après la résolution du problème de connexion par le technicien, je lui ai demandé la cause de la panne. Il m'a d'abord expliqué qu'une coupure de courant pouvait en être la source. Cependant, lorsque je lui ai confirmé que nous n'avions pas subi de coupure d'électricité, il a admis avec franchise qu'il ne connaissait pas l'origine exacte du problème.
2- Après la résolution du problème de connexion par le technicien, je lui ai demandé la cause de la panne. Il m'a d'abord expliqué qu'une coupure de courant pourrait en être la source. Cependant, lorsque je lui ai confirmé que nous n'avions pas subi de coupure d'électricité, il a admis avec franchise qu'il ne connaissait pas l'origine exacte du problème.
3- Après la résolution du problème de connexion par le technicien, je lui ai demandé la cause de la panne. Il m'a d'abord expliqué qu'une coupure de courant aurait pu en être la source. Cependant, lorsque je lui ai confirmé que nous n'avions pas subi de coupure d'électricité, il a admis avec franchise qu'il ne connaissait pas l'origine exacte du problème.
4- Après la résolution du problème de connexion par le technicien, je lui ai demandé la cause de la panne. Il m'a d'abord expliqué qu'une coupure de courant pourrait en avoir été la source. Cependant, lorsque je lui ai confirmé que nous n'avions pas subi de coupure d'électricité, il a admis avec franchise qu'il ne connaissait pas l'origine exacte du problème.
L'objectif est que le texte présenté reflète le même sens que le texte suivant:
Après la résolution du problème de connexion par le technicien, je lui ai demandé la cause de la panne. Il évoqua d'abord la possibilité d'une coupure de courant. Cependant, lorsque je lui ai confirmé que nous n'avions pas subi de coupure d'électricité, il a admis avec franchise qu'il ne connaissait pas l'origine exacte du problème.

Il est impossible de hiérarchiser les quatre possibilités proposées: toutes ajoutent à l'explication du technicien (au discours indirect) des nuances qui ne sont pas tirées du texte de départ.

1ère prop., le technicien dit: "La panne peut résulter d'une coupure de courant";
2ème prop., "La panne pourrait résulter d'une coupure de courant";
3ème prop., "La panne aurait pu résulter d'une coupure de courant";
4ème prop., "La panne pourrait avoir résulté d'une coupure de courant".

Ce sont quatre manières, toutes grammaticales, d'"évoquer une coupure de courant". Elles diffèrent par le degré de scepticisme du technicien et l'immédiateté de la causalité, or la formulation initiale ne permet pas de les estimer.
Ajouté après commentaires:

1ère prop. (indic. présent + infinitif présent) le technicien croit connaître un scénario menant réellement de la coupure de courant à la panne;
2ème prop. (cond. présent + infinitif présent) le technicien croit que la coupure cause la panne, sans pouvoir étayer sa croyance;
3ème prop. (cond. passé + infinitif présent) le technicien croit que la coupure cause la panne puis imagine des objections qui lui paraissent recevables;
4ème prop., (cond. présent + infinitif passé) le technicien croit que la coupure cause la panne, en même temps cette cause lui paraît trop éloignée de l'effet (temporellement) pour qu'il existe un scénario étayant sa croyance.

Ajouté après acceptation:
Si le vrai problème est de préserver le sens de la phrase dans un discours indirect, la solution est que le technicien décrive sans aucun jugement son activité mentale:
"{J'envisage | je considère | je conjecture | j'imagine | etc.} une coupure de courant. "
Et au discours indirect:
"Il m'a d'abord expliqué qu'il envisageait {comme cause | comme source | pour la source | etc. } une coupure de courant."

Je ne suis pas forcément d'accord avec le "degré de scepticisme". Les tournures sont de plus en plus compliquées, oui, mais cette complexité ne se traduit pas nécessairement en un "degré de scepticisme".

Si ce n'est pas ce qu'elle traduit, que traduit-elle?

Elle pourrait traduire le style de l'auteur. Ou bien, elle pourrait traduire un décalage dans le temps des actions (la fameuse concordance des temps). Plutôt cette fameuse "concordance des temps", à mon avis, si elle doit traduire quelque chose...

@FrançoisJurain Auriez-vous la gentillesse de fournir une interprétation détaillée de chaque phrase en termes de scepticisme et l'immédiateté de causalité?

Cela ne sera pas possible, car la prémisse est (au moins partiellement) incorrecte: il n'y a pas de différence de "degré" ou "d'immédiateté" entre aurait pu résulter et pourrait avoir résulté, en particulier.

@MonseigneurLavigne hélas, la gentillesse et moi ça fait deux... J'ai complété ma réponse ce nonobstant, comptant sur votre charité.

@FrançoisJurain +1. J'ai tiqué sur la 2. et la 4. mais le peu de sources que j'ai trouvées indiquent que le conditionnel présent reste en effet conditionnel présent en discours rapporté lorsque le verbe introductif est au passé. Julie affirma : « Je devrais prendre mon écharpe. » ⇒ Julie affirma qu'elle devrait prendre son écharpe. sonne tout de même très faux...

Est-ce l'emploi du passé simple qui sonne faux? Peut-être seulement parce qu'il est sorti du registre standard.

@guillaume31 en ce cas, qu'est-ce qui sonnerait juste? Car il n'est pas possible de choisir à la place de Julie le mode+temps qui lui paraissent appropriés, ni d'empêcher qu'elle ait parlé avant le moment où son propos est rapporté.

Quand on regarde le tableau de concordance des temps, il y a deux lignes qui aboutissent à un conditionnel lorsqu'on met le verbe introductif au passé : le futur simple (elle devra prendre => j'ai dit qu'elle devrait prendre) et le conditionnel, qui ne change pas (cas qui nous intéresse). Donc collision des cas. Mais si on soumet la phrase Julie a dit qu'elle devrait prendre son écharpe à n'importe qui, c'est plutôt la première hypothèse (futur) qui l'emporte spontanément. C'est pour ça que l'option 2. de la question me fait tiquer, même si effectivement c'est grammaticalement correct.

Je comprends. Revenant à notre affaire, cela donne: "La panne pourra résulter d'une coupure de courant". J'ai exclu d'emblée que ce choix (indic. futur) puisse traduire "évoquer [comme cause d'une panne actuellement constatée] une coupure de courant".

Oui, 2 ne va pas très bien. Tout est déjà au passé, la panne a déjà eu lieu. Le futur encore moins, même pour un effet de style.

@Frank Si l'on souhaitait être strictement rigoureux et respectueux de la concordance des temps, quelle serait, à votre avis, la formulation la plus grammaticalement correcte? Si aucune ne répond aux exigences mentionnées précédemment, n'hésitez pas à proposer une refonte qui incarne l'intention du texte sur lequel on se penche.
